# Allow html in asp.net textboxes

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I put ValidateRequest="false" in my page directive but the page acts like it's not posting back. If I remove the html then it posts back fine.

Using the text boxes inside an update panel shouldn't make a difference right?

I'm trying to store text in my database with html formatting.

Again, I am using an update panel.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  You're not getting the "this page may contain etc etc" exception when you enter angle brackets in the field?

Comment: I don't get any error, when I click the save button aka post back, the page acts like I didnt click it, but if I take out the html brackets it saves the data. This is probably because i'm using an update panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably getting an error behind the scenes.  If you take out the update panel do you see a nice YSOD?

If this is a .Net 4.0 application, you'll need to change the web config in order to allow for unsafe characters, even though you turned ValidateRequest to false.

The requisite change looks like this:
`<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`

Comment: yep i took out the update panels and then got the ysod. Thanks.

Comment: +1. This is a diabolical change, requiring you to opt-out in two different places just to shake off a feature that is totally wrong-headed, can't make an insecure application secure, and only gives an application that's already secure a load of bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need to put `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in web.config to be able to use the ValidateRequest feature in the page directive.