# Email address in a textbox causes PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: asp.net

I have a **multiline textbox** within an updatePanel. where a user can enter any notes he requires. If he *enters* an **email address inside angular brackets** then when submitting or cancelling I get a **PageRequestManagerServerErrorException of 500**.

If he enters an email address in these notes as `myaddress.xxx.ca` *without the brackets*, then there is *no error*.

The textbox should allow him to enter anything he wants too, it is really just for his notes.

I  have **tried** to the `RequestValidation = "false"` in the page directive but this *does not work*.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Bryan

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are *using at least .Net 4.0*? I did a small example according to your question and noted the same behaviour. Fortunatelly I found a quick solution (even here on Stackoverflow - [**Allow html in asp.net textboxes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765198/allow-html-in-asp-net-textboxes)).

**aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="commonQuestions.aspx.cs" Inherits="commonQuestions" %>
 .....
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="81px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="264px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Send" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**codeBehind**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
    Debug.WriteLine("Text: " + TextBox1.Text);
}
```

add to **web.config**

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

And here we got a pretty good **explanation** from MS, refering to [**changes in ASP.Net 4**](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147)

> As a result, request validation errors **might now occur** for requests
>   that **previously did not trigger errors**. To revert to the behavior of
>   the ASP.NET 2.0 request validation feature, add the setting *(see above)*
>   in the Web.config file: